# Passing uncertain amount of inputs to one function's sub-functions

Tags: python

Sorry if I did not explain myself clearly.
I would like to create a wrapper to call pre-defined functions with different number of inputs. Of course, I can create an individual wrapper for each function, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a generic wrapper for all cases.

The functions that should be called are named 'fun1' and 'fun2' with different number of inputs. I need to create a wrapper 'fun_wrap(func_name, uncertain amount of inputs)', which only needs the function name to be called and its associated amount of inputs.

One more thing, I need to change the input names by adding '_in' and make them global variables first. Below is my broken code. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a+b

def fun2(a,b,c):
    return a*b/c

def set_globals(**kwargs):
    for argname in kwargs:
        globals()['%s_in' % argname] = kwargs[argname]

def fun_wrap(func_name, uncertain amount of inputs):
    ffunc_name(set_globals(uncertain amount of inputs))
```

In this way, if I can call final_fun with arguments like:

```
fun_wrap(fun1,a,b)
fun_wrap(fun2,a,b)
```

UPDATE

I tried to use *arg, but failed...

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a+b

def fun2(a,b,c):
    return a*b/c

def set_globals(**kwargs):
    for argname in kwargs:
        globals()['%s_in' % argname] = kwargs[argname]

def fun_wrap(func_name, *arg):
    func_name(set_globals(*arg))

fun_wrap(fun2,a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\AppPest\rice\try.py", line 19, in <module>
    fun_wrap(fun2,a=1,b=2,c=3)
TypeError: fun_wrap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense - why are you setting these globals?

Comment: "I need to change the input names by adding '_in' and make them global variables first" -- Better go back and change `fun1` and `fun2` now, if you can.

Comment: Your are using `**kwargs` that works with keyword arguments, try with `*args` instead if you want to call your wrapper with just positional arguments like `fun_wrap(fun1, a, b)`. Also use the first argument to receive the function you will call.

Comment: @F.C.: Thanks. But I need to use **kwargs to change the name of my arguments in the set_globals(), so is there a way to combine both?

Comment: @tao.hong sure, just call the wrapper functions with keyword arguments `fun_wrap(fun1, a=a, b=b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a + b

def fun2(a,b,c):
    return a * b / c

def set_globals(**kwargs):
    for argname in kwargs:
        globals()['%s_in' % argname] = kwargs[argname]

def fun_wrap(func, **kwargs):
    set_globals(**kwargs)       # made the call to set_globals before calling your function
    return func(**kwargs)       # return the value returned by the functions called
```